# how to program greater no finder from 2 list with list comprehension in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

How to program greater no finder from 2 list with list comprehension in python3

```
l1 = [1,3,5,7]
l2 = [2,4,6,8]
new_lst = [ l1[i] for i in range(len(l1)) if l1[i] >= l2[i] else l2[i] ] #list comprehension
print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `zip` to iterate through elements from both the lists at the same time

```
>>> l1 = [1,3,5,7]
>>> l2 = [2,4,6,8] 
>>> 
>>> new_lst = [x if x >= y else y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)] 
>>> new_lst
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

Use `zip` to get tuples of pairs of elements, iterate and get the maximum:

```
l1 = [1,3,5,7]
l2 = [2,4,6,8]
new_list = [max(l) for l in zip(l1, l2)]
print(new_list)
```

This outputs

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop then append it to `new_lst`:

```
l1 = [1,3,5,7] 
l2 = [2,4,6,8]

new_lst = []

for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] >= l2[i]:
        new_lst.append(l1[i])
    else:
        new_lst.append(l2[i])
        
print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* This answer present way to fix original code, it is not intended as best solution of given task. Your original code

```
l1 = [1,3,5,7]
l2 = [2,4,6,8]
new_lst = [ l1[i] for i in range(len(l1)) if l1[i] >= l2[i] else l2[i] ]
print(new_lst)
```

cause `SyntaxError` as you put ternary `if` in wrong place - at end, which is piece for simple `if` (used for filtering, that is dropping elements not fullfilling condition). Ternary `if` is used for this or that choice based on condition and when used in comprehension its usage is like:

```
l1 = [1,3,5,7]
l2 = [2,4,6,8]
new_lst = [l1[i] if l1[i] >= l2[i] else l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]
print(new_lst)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```